# How can I remove the rounded shape around my selected tab text?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I just start learning React Native, and I added my bottom nav using Material Bottom Tabs.

My only issue is this purple circle around my icon when selected. I checked the docs looking for this default setting but couldn't find it.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    InterBold: require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Bold.ttf"),
    InterSemiBold: require("./assets/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf"),
    InterMedium: require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf"),
    InterRegular: require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf"),
    InterLight: require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Light.ttf"),
  });

  if (!loaded) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Menu principal" 
      activeColor="#f0edf6"
      inactiveColor="white"
      barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Menu principal" component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Collections" component={Collections}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Collections',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="cards" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Associations" component={Associations}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Associations',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account-group" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Classement" component={Classement} 
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Classement',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="trophy" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="News" component={News}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'News',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. You have to `npm install react-native-paper`, import, and use it.

To use react-native-paper to change the little circle tab buttons, wrap `<Tab.Navigator>...</Tab.Navigator>` with `<PaperProvider theme={theme}>` as shown below.

Finally, create a `const theme` like I did, and change the secondaryContainer to whatever color you want.

P.S. make sure to change your import names as shown to not conflict with the Provider for redux.

```
import {
  MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme,
  Provider as PaperProvider,
} from "react-native-paper";

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    secondaryContainer: "red",
  },
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Menu principal" 
          activeColor="#f0edf6"
          inactiveColor="white"
          barStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}
        >
          // rest of your code
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </PaperProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```